# What is the error in "as both are quite unpleasant experiences"?

Tags: sentence-construction, exam-questions

I got a sentence correction question, and I am having a hard time trying to figure out what and why exactly the error lies in the "as both are quite unpleasant experiences" part of the following sentence.

> You must avoid riding in a crowded bus / or travelling in a metro / during rush hour / as both are quite unpleasant experiences.

<sup>(it's one complete sentence; slashes indicate parts of the sentence)</sup>

The answer (error) is in the last part i.e. "as both are quite unpleasant experiences", but I don't know why.

Comment: Also I'm interested to know if this question has an actual answer. I keep looking at that sentence and thinking that it's totally coherent. If I was nitpicking, I'd say that they forgot a full stop. But otherwise I don't think I can answer this and English is my first language; you'd need to ask an English teacher I think.

Comment: Another native English speaker here: Nothing about the last segment seems wrong to me.  There could be some nonsensical [prescriptivist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_prescription) rule being violated that should be tossed out of the rulebook.  If I saw this sentence, I'd go with FumbleFingers and mark the "in a metro" segment wrong, but even that bit isn't so wrong as to hurt the meaning in any way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some people might think "both" doesn't correspond to "or", and thus say that you should change "or" to "and"... or change "both are.." to "either is an...".

It's not really a grammatical error.